# Problem using ffmpeg in python to decode video stream to yuv stream and send to a pipe

Tags: python, ffmpeg

This command works nice and fast in shell:

```
ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i ./myvideo.mp4 -f null -pix-fmt yuv420p -
```

It was about 13x speed or 300 frames/sec.
Then I tried to send the yuv stream to pipe and catch it the main process using the following code in python:

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-c:v', 'h264_cuvid', '-i', './myvideo.mp4', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
size_Y = int(height * width)
size_UV = int(size_Y / 4)
s = time.time()
Y = p.stdout.read(size_Y)
U = p.stdout.read(size_UV)
V = p.stdout.read(size_UV)
print('read time: ', time.time() - s)
```

However, this took seconds to read just one yuv frame. What wronged here? Im not sure what ffmpeg was sending into the pipe, the yuv planar frames or just the pointers to data planes?

the console output:

```
[('Number of Frames', 61137), ('FPS', 25.0), ('Frame Shape', (1920, 1080))]
--Number of Frames: 61137
--FPS: 25.0
--Frame Shape: (1920, 1080)
cmd:  ['ffmpeg', '-c:v', 'h264_cuvid', '-i', './myvideo.mp4', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-']
read time:  5.251002073287964
1/61137 (0.00%)read time:  2.290238618850708
2/61137 (0.00%)read time:  1.2984871864318848
3/61137 (0.00%)read time:  2.2100613117218018
4/61137 (0.01%)read time:  2.3444178104400635
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was missing. Use this cmd instead:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -c:v h264_cuvid -i ./myvideo.mp4 -f null -pix-fmt yuv420p -
```

This gives the same number of frames as original.